# По ключевым словам необходимо вывести полный адрес

Tags: python

Застрял в одном моменте и никак не могу понять. Если клиент пишет 'адрес', то необходимо вывести оба адреса. Если в слове есть адрес и ключевое слово необходимо вывести адрес в конкретном городе.

```py
client_message = 'адрес Питер '

print(client_message)

if  'адрес' in client_message:

    moscow_in_message = client_message == 'Москв' in     client_message or 'мск' in client_message
    piter_in_message = client_message == 'Петербург'in       client_message or 'Питер' in client_message

    city_is_not_mentioned = not (moscow_in_message or     piter_in_message)
  
    if  moscow_in_message or city_is_not_mentioned:
        print('Москва, ул Гагарина')

    elif piter_in_message or city_is_not_mentioned:
        print('Санкт-Петербург, ул Жукова')

    elif city_is_not_mentioned:
        print('Москва, ул Гагарина, Санкт-Петербург, ул Жукова)
```

Answer (score 2):

Если уж проверять `city_is_not_mentioned`, то раньше остальных веток, поскольку там у вас проверяется `<какое-то условие> or city_is_not_mentioned`, соответственно если его значение `True`, то сейчас у вас управление уйдёт в первую же такую ветку (выражение с `or` истинно, если истинна любая из его частей).

```
    if city_is_not_mentioned:
        print('Москва, ул Гагарина, Санкт-Петербург, ул Жукова')

    elif moscow_in_message:
        print('Москва, ул Гагарина')

    elif piter_in_message:
        print('Санкт-Петербург, ул Жукова')
```

Но на самом деле вариант `city_is_not_mentioned` вообще не нужно проверять, поскольку он истинен только в случае если оба значения `moscow_in_message` и `piter_in_message` ложны, и в итоге вообще можно обойтись без переменной `city_is_not_mentioned`:

```
    if  moscow_in_message:
        print('Москва, ул Гагарина')

    elif piter_in_message:
        print('Санкт-Петербург, ул Жукова')

    else:
        print('Москва, ул Гагарина, Санкт-Петербург, ул Жукова')
```

У вас, правда, ещё никак не обрабатывается вариант, если пользователь укажет сразу оба города. Но видимо пока можно считать, что ввод всегда корректный и такого не будет.

**Update:**
В определении условий тоже лишнее написано, `client_message == ...` не нужно, конечно, его убрать, остальное верно. Получится так:

```
    moscow_in_message = 'Москв' in client_message or 'мск' in client_message
    piter_in_message = 'Петербург' in client_message or 'Питер' in client_message
```

Comment: Все равно не корректные данные показывает . При запросе 'адрес в Москве'  показывает оба адреса. Может проблема в строке где определяется истинность true?

Comment: @Глеб Да, и там тоже проблемы, сделал добавление